# Weird issue in collision resolution of non-static bodies

Tags: go, collision-detection, game-engine, game-physics

I'm a bit of a beginner in engine development, so I decided to write my own engine from scratch so I could learn more about what happens under everything.

I've been progressing fairly well, except the physics engine side of things have been giving me a bit of a headache.

Here's a gif of what I mean:

[image: Weird collision issue]

Essentially, the engine works just fine as long as the player is not colliding with another non-static body from either above or from right to left.

Here's my collision resolution code written in go:

```
package resources

import (
  "game/pidgeot-socket/ecs"

  "github.com/bxcodec/saint"
)

type PhysicsSystem struct {
  Hub *Hub
}

func (system PhysicsSystem) Loop() {
  entities, err := system.Hub.World.AllEntitiesWithComponent(ecs.CollisionComponent)
  if err != nil { return }

  for e, _ := range entities {
    // apply impulse
    c_p, _ := system.Hub.World.GetComponent(e, ecs.CollisionComponent)
    c := (*c_p).(*ecs.Collision)

    p_p, _ := system.Hub.World.GetComponent(e, ecs.PositionComponent)
    p := (*p_p).(*ecs.Position)

    if c.WithGravity {
      // Add gravity
      c.ImpulseY = saint.Min(c.ImpulseY + 1, c.MaxSpeedY)
    }

    // apply impulse
    p.NextY = p.Y + c.ImpulseY
    p.NextX = p.X + c.ImpulseX
  }

  // resolving collisions
  for e1, _ := range entities {
    c1_p, _ := system.Hub.World.GetComponent(e1, ecs.CollisionComponent)
    c1 := (*c1_p).(*ecs.Collision)

    if c1.IsStatic { continue }

    for e2, _ := range entities {
      if e1 == e2 { continue }

      system.ResolveCollision(entities, e1, e2)
    }
  }

  // moving entities
  for e, _ := range entities {
    p_p, _ := system.Hub.World.GetComponent(e, ecs.PositionComponent)
    p := (*p_p).(*ecs.Position)

    if (p.X != p.NextX || p.Y != p.NextY) {
      p.X = p.NextX
      p.Y = p.NextY

      system.Hub.broadcast <- system.Hub.World.GetComponentMessage(e, p_p)
    }
  }
}

func (system PhysicsSystem) ResolveCollision(entities map[ecs.EID]*ecs.Component, e1 ecs.EID, e2 ecs.EID) {
  c1_p, _ := system.Hub.World.GetComponent(e1, ecs.CollisionComponent)
  p1_p, _ := system.Hub.World.GetComponent(e1, ecs.PositionComponent)
  c1 := (*c1_p).(*ecs.Collision)
  p1 := (*p1_p).(*ecs.Position)

  c2_p, _ := system.Hub.World.GetComponent(e2, ecs.CollisionComponent)
  p2_p, _ := system.Hub.World.GetComponent(e2, ecs.PositionComponent)
  c2 := (*c2_p).(*ecs.Collision)
  p2 := (*p2_p).(*ecs.Position)

  // resolve y-axis
  collidingX := IsOverlapping(p1.X, p1.X + c1.W, p2.X, p2.X + c2.W)
  collidingY := IsOverlapping(p1.NextY, p1.NextY + c1.H, p2.NextY, p2.NextY + c2.H)
  colliding := collidingX && collidingY

  if colliding {
    direction := func (impulse int) int {if impulse < 0 { return 1 } else { return -1 }}(c1.ImpulseY)
    overlap := CalculateOverlap(p1.NextY, p1.NextY + c1.H, p2.NextY, p2.NextY + c2.H)

    p1.NextY += (direction * overlap)
    c1.ImpulseY = 0
    c1.IsJumping = false
  }

  // resolve x-axis
  collidingX = IsOverlapping(p1.NextX, p1.NextX + c1.W, p2.NextX, p2.NextX + c2.W)
  collidingY = IsOverlapping(p1.Y, p1.Y + c1.H, p2.Y, p2.Y + c2.H)
  colliding = collidingX && collidingY

  if colliding {
    direction := func (impulse int) int {if impulse < 0 { return 1 } else { return -1 }}(c1.ImpulseX)
    overlap := CalculateOverlap(p1.NextX, p1.NextX + c1.W, p2.NextX, p2.NextX + c2.W)

    p1.NextX += (direction * overlap)
  }

  for e3, _ := range entities {
    if e1 == e3 { continue }

    c3_p, _ := system.Hub.World.GetComponent(e3, ecs.CollisionComponent)
    p3_p, _ := system.Hub.World.GetComponent(e3, ecs.PositionComponent)
    c3 := (*c3_p).(*ecs.Collision)
    p3 := (*p3_p).(*ecs.Position)

    collidingX = IsOverlapping(p1.NextX, p1.NextX + c1.W, p3.NextX, p3.NextX + c3.W)
    collidingY = IsOverlapping(p1.NextY, p1.NextY + c1.H, p3.NextY, p3.NextY + c3.H)
    colliding = collidingX && collidingY

    if colliding { system.ResolveCollision(entities, e1, e3) }
  }
}
```

Anything I could do to solve that issue?

Comment: It looks like the code is written to do exactly what appears in the GIF, how do you want it to behave?

Comment: I would like for the character to stand on top of the enemy if falling from the top, and for the character to stop moving if colliding with the enemy from the right to left. I just don't see where I'm making my mistake, and I've been staring at this code for over two weeks now...

Comment: It looks like you do your Y-axis resolution, update `NextY`, then do your X-axis resolution, which doesn't know you've already resolved Y-axis and they no longer overlap, so it moves them to the side as well.

Comment: It still doesn't work. If I change `collidingX := IsOverlapping(p1.X, p1.X + c1.W, p2.X, p2.X + c2.W)` to `collidingX := IsOverlapping(p1.NextX, p1.NextX + c1.W, p2.NextX, p2.NextX + c2.W)` and do the same for the Y coordinates, now the character just slides through all the way to the end of the area block, and falls through